# Python (32 bit) stops responding

Tags: python, pygame, path-finding, a-star

Below, I have attached the code of my implementation of A* (star) search. I made a basic pygame interface. 
I know it is not near perfection in any way.

**The problem I faced:**
1. When I added more than 5-6 barriers, (i checked task manager) python and the pygame [window stopped responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49kvT.jpg) after the program ran for a couple of seconds. Although, it stopped responding, it continued to use the system's CPU and mermory.

What I know: This issue is not system specific as i made my friend (who had a far better pc) run it and he encountered the same problem.

How this code runs:

1. The first click on the grid is the starting position
2. The second click is the target position.
3. Any of the subsequent clicks are barriers placed in the grid.
4. Press 'r' to start pathfinding.

Could this be due to the inefficiency of my code or some other reason? Please help me!

**Code:**

```
import pygame
from math import sqrt


def draw_grid():
    global win, dist, width
    for x in range(0, width, dist):
        pygame.draw.line(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, 0), (x, width))
    for y in range(0, width, dist):
        pygame.draw.line(win, (255, 255, 255), (0, y), (width, y))


def make_barrier(x, y, color=(0, 100, 155)):
    global win
    print(x, y, "drawn", color)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, color, (x+1, y+1, dist-2, dist-2))
    pygame.display.update()


def g_or_h(block1, block2):
    x1, y1 = block1
    x2, y2 = block2
    return sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)


def start_pathfinding(start, target):
    open_nodes.append([start, start, g_or_h(start, start), g_or_h(start, target)+g_or_h(start, start)])
    new_nodes()


def new_nodes():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    global open_nodes, closed_nodes
    current = open_nodes[0]
    # if current[0] == target:
    #     path_found(current)
    current_x, current_y = current[0]
    # Neighbours:
    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            if (i, j) != (0, 0):
                valid_neighbour = True
                neighbour_x = current_x + i*dist
                neighbour_y = current_y + j*dist
                g = g_or_h(current[0], [neighbour_x, neighbour_y]) + current[2]
                f = g_or_h(target, [neighbour_x, neighbour_y]) + g
                neighbour_node = [[neighbour_x, neighbour_y], current[0], g, f]
                if neighbour_node[0] == target:
                    path_found(current)
                # Neighbour in barrier:
                for barrier in barriers:
                    if [neighbour_x, neighbour_y] == barrier:
                        valid_neighbour = False
                        print(1)
                        break
                for closed_node in closed_nodes:
                    if [neighbour_x, neighbour_y] == closed_node[0]:
                        valid_neighbour = False
                        print(1)
                        break
                found_in_open = False
                if valid_neighbour is True:
                    for open_node in open_nodes:
                        if [neighbour_x, neighbour_y] == open_node[0] and open_node[3] > f:
                            open_node[3] = f
                            open_node[1] = current
                            found_in_open = True
                            print(2)
                            break

                    if found_in_open is False:
                        open_nodes.append(neighbour_node)
                        print(neighbour_node)
    print("*"*20)
    open_nodes.remove(current)
    closed_nodes.append(current)


    for ni in range(len(open_nodes)):
        for nj in range(len(open_nodes)):
            if open_nodes[ni][3] < open_nodes[nj][3]:
                open_nodes[ni], open_nodes[nj] = open_nodes[nj], open_nodes[ni]

    new_nodes()


def path_found(final_node):
    parent = final_node[1]
    while parent != start:
        path.append(parent)
        for element in closed_nodes:
            if element[0] == parent:
                path_found(element)
    print(path)
    draw_path()


def draw_path():
    for element in path:
        x, y = element
        make_barrier(x, y, color=(255, 255, 255))
   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Drawing the window and grid
    rows = 20
    width = 500
    dist = width//rows
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Basic Window")
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    draw_grid()

    # Main loop and globally required variables
    barriers = []
    running = True
    count = 0
    pathfinder = False
    open_nodes = []
    closed_nodes = []
    path = []
    while running:
        # event = pygame.event.wait()
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0):
            x_pos, y_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x_pos = x_pos // dist * dist
            y_pos = y_pos // dist * dist
            if count == 0:
                start = [x_pos, y_pos]
                make_barrier(x_pos, y_pos, color=(0, 255, 0))
                count += 1
            elif count == 1 and [x_pos, y_pos] != start:
                target = [x_pos, y_pos]
                make_barrier(x_pos, y_pos, color=(255, 0, 0))
                count += 1
            elif count > 1 and pathfinder is False:
                if [x_pos, y_pos] not in barriers and [x_pos, y_pos] != start and [x_pos, y_pos] != target:
                    make_barrier(x_pos, y_pos)
                    barriers.append([x_pos, y_pos])
                count += 1

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print(barriers)
                running = False
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    pathfinder = True

        if pathfinder is True:
            start_pathfinding(start, target)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: It runs fine on my machine, I would suggest to update pygame to `2.0.0.dev6` or newer if availbale. Also you will improve performance with controlling `FPS` by adding `clock.tick(FPS)`.

Comment: @kaktus_car I updated pygame, it improved the performance a little. However, in larger and complex mazes, my program either randomly stops responding or stops responding just after the path is found and before it it drawn, i still cannot figure out what causes it.

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought it stops when you draw barriers. Now when I ran it, I get the same results as you. Unfortunately, I was unable to spot the issue